# Check open and close time in 3 different cases

Tags: c#, datetime, math, logic

I have 2 variables

1. `DateTime closingTime`
2. `TimeSpan diffTime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(endtime);`

I would like to check 3 cases:

1. the store is open n hours and n minutes
2. the store is open n minutes
3. the store is closed

**my code:**

```
if(diffTime.Minutes > 0 || diffTime.Hours == 0 )
    _timeLeft = "Noch " + diffTime.Minutes.ToString() + " Minuten geöffnet";
if (diffTime.Hours > 0)
    _timeLeft = "Noch " + diffTime.Hours.ToString() + " Stunden und " + diffTime.Minutes.ToString() + " Minuten geöffnet";
else
    //Der Markt ist derzeit geschlossen, 
    _timeLeft = "Feierabend!";
```

Is it possible without the "openingTime"?

Comment: My assumption (is the mother of all mistakes). At day x: store opens at Topen and closes at Tclose. 
Most likely you need to know if the store is already open: so between Topen and Tclose
If you want to calculate how long the store is already open, then you need to know Topen. 
If you only want to calculate for how long the store will be open and you know that the store is open, then all you need is Tclose.
But as stated before you can only have this knowledge if you know Topen.

Comment: Instead of `||` use `&&` otherwise you'll always fall into this case. But I think that the best would be to use open & close time. This is how real life works.

Comment: with openingTime it definitely works, it works for real, no doubt about it!
the question: Does it works without the "openingTime"?

Comment: How can it? what if the store is not opened yet?

Comment: @Aisac without knowing the opening times, you can't determine whether the store is open or closed. If you have a night shop, the closing time could even be smaller than the opening time.

Comment: @ErwinvanDijk
[Open time code](https://gist.github.com/aimore/e5968184ebc9e3a2cdb92b2960aa8a98)

Answer (score 0):

No way to proof all 3 cases just with closingTime and DateTime.Now

```
if ((DateTime.Now > openingTime) && (DateTime.Now < closingTime) && diffTime.Hours == 0)
    _timeLeft = "Noch " + diffTime.Minutes.ToString() + " Minuten geöffnet";
else if ((DateTime.Now > openingTime) && (DateTime.Now < closingTime))
    _timeLeft = "Noch " + diffTime.Hours.ToString() + " Stunden und " + diffTime.Minutes.ToString() + " Minuten geöffnet";
else
//Der Markt ist derzeit geschlossen, 
    _timeLeft = "Feierabend!";
```